# ¿Cómo comparo una letra ingresada por el usuario con una predefinida en C?

Tags: c, condiciones, lógica

Necesito solicitar una letra al usuario para poder crear una interfaz especial dependiendo de lo que el usuario elija. Sin embargo, al momento de comparar la variante siempre me arroja un resultado invalido ya que detecta que el carácter ingresado por el usuario es diferente a los dos que determinan la interfaz, aun si son la misma letra.
Muestro una pequeña prueba que presenta dicho error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char letra;
    printf("Comparar una letra con la letra A\n\n\n");
    
    printf("Ingrese una letra\n");
    scanf("%c",&letra);
    
    if(letra=="A")
        printf("%c es igual a A",letra);
    else
        printf("%c es diferente a A",letra);
}
```

Comment: Intenta reemplazar las comillas por comillas simples letra == 'A'

Answer (score 2):

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) los literales de carácter se escriben con comillas simples (`'A'`), los literales de texto se escriben con comillas dobles (`"A"`).

- El literal `'A'` es un carácter, su tipo es `char`.
- El literal `"A"` es una cadena de caracteres, su tipo es `char[2]`.

No puedes comparar `char` con `char[2]`, probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
if(letra=='A') // Comillas simples
```